# Can javax.persistence.Query.getResultList() return null?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

And if so, under what circumstances?

Javadoc and JPA spec says nothing.

Comment: I was searching exactly this question! tks! up 4 you!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You are right. JPA specification says nothing about it. But **Java Persistence with Hibernate book, 2nd edition**, says:

> If the query result is empty, a null is returned

Hibernate JPA implementation (Entity Manager) return null when you call query.getResultList() with no result.

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by some users, it seems that a newest version of Hibernate returns an empty list instead.

An empty list is returned in Eclipselink as well when no results are found.

Comment: This is certainly outdated, Hibernate returns an empty list.

Comment: I still get null from Hibernate 4.3.10 (running as JPA engine for Spring Data). This only happens for a single native query, as typical JPA queries work as expected.

Comment: Just check for both conditions using OR. `if(rows == null || rows.size == 0){}` where rows is what the getResultList() returns

Comment: Just wrap it in an Optional.ofNullable() and you're set.

Comment: I believe returning `null` instead of an empty list is not what is intended by the spec as it otherwise makes it quite clear when to expect `null` in other places. Especially as the documentation for `getResultList` reads `Execute a SELECT query and return the query results as a(n) (un)typed List. - @return a list of the results`. I'd still check for `null` of course and return an empty list myself if needed.

Answer (score 25):

If the specs said it could't happen, would you belive them? Given that your code could conceivably run against may different JPA implementations, would you trust every implementer to get it right?

No matter what, I would code defensively and check for null.

Now the big question: should we treat "null" and an empty List as synonymous? This is where the specs should help us, and don't.

My guess  is that a null return (if indeed it could happen) would be equivalent to "I didn't understand the query" and empty list would be "yes, understood the query, but there were no records".

You perhaps have a code path (likely an exception) that deals with unparsable queries, I would tend to direct a null return down that path.

Comment: +1 you are so right when saying: "would you trust every JPA provider?" NO :)

Comment: Edited to add: Arthur has pointed out that Hibernate's JPA in fact returns null if no records are found. So in fact in this case, we do need to fold together null and empty list. I believe that the thought process we went through above is still valid.

It is even conceivable that we should have different treatments of null for different JPA stacks. Welcome to portability fun.

Comment: Agreed. There only exists "portability fun" due to the JPA spec not doing what it should do ... specify the precise semantics. Shame it is run by committee with vested interests.

Comment: "I didn't understand query" should be handled as `Exception`, returning `null` where `Collection` is in return type is an obvious design flaw

Answer (score 14):

Contrary to Arthur's post, when I actually ran a query which no entities matched I got an empty list, not null. This is using Hibernate and is what I consider correct behaviour: an empty list is the correct answer when you ask for a collection of entities and there aren't any.

Comment: for OpenJPA, I also get a empty list instead of null.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a close look at the `org.hibernate.loader.Loader` (4.1) you will see that the list is always initialized inside the processResultSet() method ([doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/loader/Loader.html#processResultSet(java.sql.ResultSet,%20org.hibernate.engine.spi.QueryParameters,%20org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor,%20boolean,%20org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer,%20int,%20java.util.List)), [source](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/loader/Loader.java#L961)).

```
protected List processResultSet(...) throws SQLException {
   final List results = new ArrayList();

   handleEmptyCollections( queryParameters.getCollectionKeys(), rs, session );
   ...
   return results;

}
```

So I don't think it will return null now.

Comment: Cheers for the exact code snippet. But this answer focuses on just hibernate which is one of the implementation of the specification. Other implementation like OpenJPA differ in the behavior. Also, hibernate seems to have changed the behavior over different versions.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if you test the result set with Jakarta's CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty, you're covered either way.

Answer (score 1):

`Query.getResultList()` returns an empty list instead of `null`. So check `isEmpty()` in the returned result, and continue with the rest of the logic if it is false.

Answer (score 0):

Given the implementation of `getResultsList()` in `org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl` class, it is possible to return a `null` :

```
public List getResultList() {
    try {
        return query.list();
    }
    catch (QueryExecutionRequestException he) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(he);
    }
    catch( TypeMismatchException e ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
    catch (HibernateException he) {
        em.throwPersistenceException( he );
        return null;
    }
```

My hibernate version is: 3.3.1.GA