# Order of items in List relationship

Tags: java, jpa, orm

This may be super easy but I can't find any clear statement about it in JPA specs. If I have a `List`-based relationship without `@OrderBy` annotation, e.g:

```
@OneToMany
List<Child> children;
```

then what will be order of this list elements in Java? It seems reasonable that this will be order of corresponding records in `Child` table or entries in intermetiate table if it's many to many, but is that a **guaranteed** behavior of JPA providers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order is not guaranteed by the specification as far as I know. [@OrderBy](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html) is the way to go if you depend on the order.

EDIT: Quote from JPA 1.0 spec:

> Portable applications should not expect the order of lists to be maintained across persistence contexts unless the OrderBy construct is used and the modifications to the list observe the specified ordering. The order is not otherwise persistent.

(Page 19, Footnote [4])

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: @PiotrSobczyk I edited the answer with a quote from the spec.

Comment: Wow, thank you for finding it! It definitely clears things out!

Answer (score 2):

Also, when your entity has no children, JPA specs don't specify if it should return an empty list or null when you retrieve your List, so be sure to check it to avoid nullpointerexceptions.

Comment: Didn't know about that! Good to know that one.

Comment: Just found this! more info about specs & implementations: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1115480/1385048

Answer (score 1):

There is no guaranteed behavior, the order can be different each time. It happened to me with hibernate: the order changed when I refreshed the page.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to order the search result when you search, not in the definition of the class and its properties.

Comment: It's not about ordering search result, i.e. order of `Parent` entites returned by query but ordering of collection of related entities (i.e. `chilren` list) in a given `Parent` instance. I can't determine it in query. The only way I know to do it is by @OrderBy annotation (see: http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/OrderBy), but I'm asking is there any guaranteed order if I don't use @OrderBy.