# JPA MERGE failed to update entity field value when this field is a collection(using ElementCollection)

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

Here we have a Manifest class that includes list of students and teachers, both could be null.

```
class Manifest{
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "MANIFEST_STUDENT")
    List<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "MANIFEST_TEACHER")
    List<String> teachers = new ArrayList<String>();;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "MANIFEST_OTHERS")
    List<String> others = new ArrayList<String>();;
}
```

on the UI, there are two `multiple select`, one for `student` and one for `teacher` that let user choose for current manifest.

here is the problem:

When user `deselect` all `students` or `teachers` from the list(meaning remove all students or teachers from current `manifest`) and click save, unfortunately nothing can be saved, from UI and database it shows that the `multiselect` chosen looks the `SAME` as before.

from service layer, the code is simply like this.

```
manifest.merge();
```

It seems we must keep `at least one` student or teacher for the collection field to make the change valid. So what's going on here and what is the solution? BTW, we are on Openjpa.

Comment: You're leaving us guessing to a lot of detail. Making assumptions on our part isn't likely to help you. Providing JPA annotations, some (simple) idea of table schema's, etc, would help. Since you've identified this as a JPA issue, we're no longer interested in your UI, or how it works. Such detail only confuse the core issue. Talk to exactly how your code (possibly in the UI) is interacting with the JPA entity. What gets set, and how. Simple code snippets would help. Finally, show exceptions, if such are generated. They are relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of resolve the issue, more like a work around:

Before calling `merge()`, place several condition checkers to make sure the collection fields are not null

```
public void save(Manifest entity) {

    if(entity.getStudents()==null){
        entity.setStudents(new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    if(entity.getTeachers()==null){
        entity.setTeachers(new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    if(entity.getOthers()==null){
        entity.setOthers(new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    entity.merge();
}
```

Simple as it, it seems the UI returns those collection fields as null even we initiate them as with empty String lists.

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a value in a JPA managed class, such as `class Manifest`, has no bearing on what, or how, JPA will create the class as JPA maps extracted rows to the class.  In particular, the result of:

```
List<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();
```

is likely to be:

- On creation (by JPA) of a new instance, assign an `ArrayList<String>()` to `students`.
- JPA overwrites `students` with the data it extracts - the empty `ArrayList` is dereferenced/lost.

If your code is clearing a list, such as `students`, use `obj.getStudents().clear()`.  More likely to run into problems if you call `obj.setStudents(someEmptyList)`.

The issue here is how the JPA manager handles empty datasets: as `null` or as an *empty list*.  The JPA spec (old, not sure about the just released update) doesn't take a position on this point.  A [relevant article here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1115480/1448212).

From your comments, it's apparent that OpenJPA may not be respecting a `null` value for a `Collection`/`List`, while it happily manages the necessary changes for when the value is set to an empty list instead.  Someone knowing more about OpenJPA than I may be able to help at this stage - meanwhile you've got a workaround.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks. So two questions: (1)if `obj.getStudents()` is null , can I still use `clear()` method? (2)what problem could happen when calling `obj.setStudents(someEmptyList)`?

Comment: 1. `clear`ly not.  2. my own personal paranoia, when running into problems.  The *real* issue, not yet addressed (IMHO due to lack of detail in the problem statement) is *why* are these values `null`?  You imply that there is a "problem" - so what is it?  What exception?  What's in the data tables before and after the merge - and what's in the object before it's modified, and then after it's modified and just prior to the merge?

Comment: it is a spring MVC application, Spring interpret dom list values from UI(even sir you are not interested :), but still that's a fact) as null, like I mentioned, when user deselect all options and click save button. There is no exception. i.e. user want's to remove everyone from student list, currently it only holds Adam and Bob. After user deselect them both and hit save, the page should show no one selected on student list. But A and B still there. What I can see using debugging mode is, the manifest object return stundents==null, after I remove A and B and hit save button.

Comment: I'm making guesses again, not keyed into OpenJPA, but what happens if you change the setter thus: setStudents(List<String> students) { if (students == null) this.students.clear(); else this.students = students; }

Comment: I'm suggesting that there may be a *bug* (or, for OpenJPA purists, possibly a feature :-) and a possible workaround.

Comment: Do you mean what happens after I change the setter then? It resolves my issue. Now after I remove A&B and hit save button, the page does show me the students list are cleared. But I think it is just a work around, because JPA should do such setter explicitly. I hope there is an annotation or option to do so.. but seems not avaiable. Then also seems the `clear()` method doesn't apply here