# javax.persistence.Query.getResultList() returning null list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

I am using  `getResultList  ( List javax.persistence.Query.getResultList() )` in my dao to fetch a list of objects. Any idea why it may return  `{null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null}`  for a query which was has no match in the db. This is causing my code List. `hasNext()`  to break which was working fine earlier. I wasn't working in this project for a while (If it matters). It's using

> hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final-sources.jar

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115480/can-javax-persistence-query-getresultlist-return-null) and understands it is returning list now.

- Since which version this change has come to effect?
- How the hibernate decide the size of this list?
- How to stay away from this kind of errors in general?

Comment: The linked post does not explain the results that you are describing. It says that the returned list is `null` and not that it returns a list of `null` elements. And as your results seem to come from a query that _has_ 10 matches in the DB (which each is `null`), you will have to provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you finding out what is going wrong.

Comment: Thinking about the `10` I guess I found the explanation (see below) - although I don't know what you mean with _causing my code List.hasNext() to break which was working fine earlier_

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing: You checked your list in the debugger and didn't look at the `size` property? Hibernate returns an `ArrayList` without an explicit `capacity` in many cases. And the `ArrayList` initializes its internal array with 10 `null` elements then (to avoid creating an array again and again while adding elements). But if you ask `list.iterator().hasNext()` it should return `false` (as well as `list.isEmpty()` returns `true` and `list.size()` returns `0`).

Answer (score -1):

Just add an `isEmpty` check on the result list:

```
List<SomeType> resultList = query.getResultList();
if (resultList.isEmpty()){
    //Handle it
}
```

The result list somehow always contains some nulls, I used the isEmpty check to prevent errors later on.

Comment: From Tobias Liefke answer list.iterator().hasNext() should return false as well as list.isEmpty() returns true. So basically both should do fine. So how is isEmpty going to help?

Comment: `isEmpty` is a fast check to see if any iterating should be done at all. You could take the list's iterator and and check `hasNext()`, hell I'll admit it even looks nicer, though why iterate if you can just loop over the list after the isEmpty check?  Additionally, by the time I posted this, I hadn't read the comment yet and simply wanted to help you since I've had to work with JPA and Hibernate for the last 3 weeks at work and ran into the problem myself ;)

Comment: @RBz Can you tell me than, if I was right with my guess? And why did your iterator did _break_?

Answer (score -2):

You could prevent this by checking for null elements in your List.hasNext().

```
 if(variable = list.next() !=null)  
    // do something
```

Comment: The question was not how to deal with `null` values, but how to prevent them.

Answer (score -2):

- At least version 3.2.7
- To avoid these kind of crashes, always *always* verify input. Whether you pull it from forms, databases, files or whatever kind of source. Verify that what you receive is what you expect it to be, otherwise discard/omit it.

Comment: In a fail-fast system you should never just omit or discard data that is not matching the expected structure, syntax or interface. Instead you should reject such an input and stop execution (it is even better to have a NPE in that case instead of an error which is raised later on).

Comment: That's actually exactly what I'm saying, haha. I'm not saying you should discard only the part of the input, but the whole input. And if that doesn't match, don't process it (so discard the input).