# Does the javax.persistence.query.getresultlist() return null if it did not find anything?

Tags: jpa

If the javax.persistence.query.getresultlist() is successfully executed, meaning that it did not throw any exception, but simply the query did not find any matching result in the database will it return null or a List with size() = 0 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115480/can-javax-persistence-query-getresultlist-return-null

Comment: An empty list, but what stops you from checking it by your self?

Answer (score 0):

It will return a `List` with `size() = 0`
and if you try to access this list with get method you will get `ArrayOutOfBound Exception`

Comment: Is this true for all hibernate versions? for all JPA implementations?