# Result of JPA named query mapped to a list of pojo doesn't return an empty list when no data is received from query execution

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a named query in **jpa**(**hibernate implementation**), the result of which is to be mapped to a list of custom pojo(`myresult.java`). In one case the query doesn't return any values and I was expecting an empty list to be returned. Instead I am getting a list with one object of type "`myresult`", with all the members initialized as null.
I don't understand why this is happening...any help is much appreciated..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: List<myresult> result = (List<myresult>)(em.createNamedQuery("Entity1.returnRequiredSets", myresult.class).setParameter("inputTime", null).getResultList()); returnRequiredSets is a named query in my Entity1.java entity. It is: select distinct fileNos from Accounts where date =:inputTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of trials I found that Jpa hibernate implementation has it that if only aggregated values are to be returned from a named query then in "no data" case, an empty list of pojos is not returned. Instead a list with a single object which has appropriate defaults set for attributes (null for sum, 0 for count etc) is returned. However, if only column values or column values along with aggregates are selected, then an empty list will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of your problem is explained in this link

[Can javax.persistence.Query.getResultList() return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115480/can-javax-persistence-query-getresultlist-return-null)

In JPA in place to return empty, returns a null, then in your case add null to the list to return, I worked with spring-data and return a empty list, i dont know why hibernate decide to use this approach in place of return an empty list

Comment: thanks for the response....but the issue I am facing is that I am not getting an empty list when the query isn't returning anything...(inputTime is passed as null)...I have a (result.isEmpty()) check which is failing..

Comment: yes i am afraid you will have to compare if the first element is null or not according to what says the post